# Outlook 2016 VSTO Context Menu Button

Tags: xml, outlook, vsto

I am trying to add a button to the outlook hyperlink context menu. The xml below has some sample buttons added to the add-in menu - these work. Just can't get the context menu one to work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"    onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
<ribbon>
<tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabAddIns">
        <group id="ContentGroup" label="Content">
      <button id="textButton" label="Insert Text"
           screentip="Text" onAction="OnTextButton"
           supertip="Inserts text at the cursor location."/>
    </group>
  </tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
  <contextMenus>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuHyperlink">
      <button id="Testing..." label="test"
          onAction="onButtonTest"/>
    </contextMenu>
  </contextMenus> 
</customUI>
```

Answer (score -1):

Outlook has two different `idMso` for compose and read scenarios as follow ...

- Compose view `idMso="ContextMenuHyperlink"`
- Read view `idMso="ContextMenuReadOnlyMailHyperlink"`

You didn't specified in which scenario you are loading your ribbon XML, but I guess you want to have your item appear in the context menu of the read view. In this case your code should looks like ...

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="explorerRibbonLoaded">
  <contextMenus>    
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuReadOnlyMailHyperlink">
      <button id="btnTesting" label="test" onAction="onButtonTest" visible="true"/>
    </contextMenu>
  </contextMenus>
</customUI>
```

Which will be resulting to the following view ...

[image]

Comment: Thanks Slava. That worked and you are correct it was read view that I was after. 
One other question: how do I get the link to the href that was right clicked on?

Cheers,

Comment: @KevinE i believe somebody already answered on this question: [Outlook hyperlink context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509147/outlook-hyperlink-context-menu). I didn't try it myself, but this would be good start for you. If you satisfied with the answer on your original question consider accepting it, it will help others to find solution quickly. Accepting Answers: [How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)