# Get clicked hyperlink from reading pane

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have an Outlook VSTO add-in that adds a button to the hyperlink context menu (using `idMso="ContextMenuReadOnlyMailHyperlink"`) and I would like to get the clicked hyperlink.

Thanks to the post [how to add a new option to context menu of hyperlink in an email for Outlook 2010?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8c004bb1-398f-44be-bcde-a54ec523ee69/how-to-add-a-new-option-to-context-menu-of-hyperlink-in-an-email-for-outlook-2010), I managed to get the clicked hyperlink when the mail is opened in a new window. The post suggested using `ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor` for mails within the reading pane, but that did not work for me as it is always `null`.

According to the post [Outlook hyperlink context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509147/outlook-hyperlink-context-menu), `ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor` cannot be used in this context and `Explorer.Selection` should be used instead. I have tried following that direction yet no luck in getting the clicked hyperlink. The `Word.Selection` seems to be pointing at the beginning of the mail instead of pointing at the clicked hyperlink, as it returns to the first letter of the mail.

How can I get the clicked hyperlink from the reading pane?

```
// mail in new window
if (control.Context is Inspector inspector)
{
    Document document = inspector.WordEditor;
    if (document != null && document.Windows != null && document.Windows.Count > 0)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection word = document.Windows[1].Selection;
        if (word != null && word.Hyperlinks != null && word.Hyperlinks.Count > 0)
        {
            Hyperlink hyperlink = word.Hyperlinks[1];
            MessageBox.Show(hyperlink.Address); // output: the clicked hyperlink
        }
    }
}
// mail in reading pane
else if (control.Context is Explorer explorer)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Selection selection = explorer.Selection;
    if (selection[1] is MailItem mailItem)
    {
        Inspector inspector = mailItem.GetInspector;
        Document document = inspector.WordEditor;
        if (document != null && document.Windows != null && document.Windows.Count > 0)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection word = document.Windows[1].Selection;
            if (word != null && word.Hyperlinks != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(word.Hyperlinks.Count.ToString()); // output: 0
                MessageBox.Show(word.Text); // output: the first letter of the mail
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One may get the clicked hyperlink with either [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeExplorer.htm)'s `ReadingPane` or [Outlook 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.previewpane)'s `PreviewPane`. I went with `PreviewPane` but note that it is only available in Outlook 2016 or newer versions.

The difficult part was to get the correct interop reference that contains the `PreviewPane` property. The common practice is to remove the old assembly references and add the object library in the COM tab, but that did not work for me because of GAC and I could not find a way to bypass GAC successfully. I ended up using late binding to access the property.

Posting the full code below, hope it will help anyone else with the same problem since all other answers I found online were either outdated or does not have sufficient information to understand / replicate them.

```
public void GetSelected(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    Document document = null;
    // mail in new window
    if (control.Context is Inspector inspector)
    {
        document = inspector.WordEditor;
    }
    // mail in reading pane
    else if (control.Context is Explorer explorer)
    {
        try
        {
            // late binding for Explorer.PreviewPane.WordEditor
            Type eType = explorer.GetType();
            var pane = eType.InvokeMember(
                "PreviewPane",
                BindingFlags.GetProperty,
                null, explorer, new object[] { });
            Type pType = pane.GetType();
            document = pType.InvokeMember(
                "WordEditor",
                BindingFlags.GetProperty,
                null, pane, new object[] { }) as Document;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Require Outlook 2016 or newer");
            return;
        }
    }
    // get right clicked hyperlink from document
    if (document != null && document.Windows != null && document.Windows.Count > 0)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection selection = document.Windows[1].Selection;
        if (selection != null && selection.Hyperlinks != null && selection.Hyperlinks.Count > 0)
        {
            Hyperlink hyperlink = selection.Hyperlinks[1];
            // the right clicked hyperlink
            MessageBox.Show(hyperlink.Address);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No selection or hyperlink");
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No document");
    }
}
```

fyi I have [another post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/eed4f4e0-56cd-4856-8ee3-597ca44cc250/get-clicked-hyperlink-from-reading-pane?forum=outlookdev) on MSDN which has more information on what I have tried to reach this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm must be:

1. Check if `Application.ActiveWindow` is `Inspector`. Use `Application.ActiveWindow.WordEditor` if it is.
2. Otherwise, cast `Application.ActiveWindow` to `Explorer`
3. Check if `Explorer.ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor` is not null. Use it.
4. Otherwise, use `Explorer.PreviewPane.WordEditor`

Comment: I believe the first three points are what I have done, while point 3 is always null. Would like to use `Explorer.PreviewPane.WordEditor` but I am having trouble in getting the `PreviewPane` property loaded. Still finding a way to get the correct outlook interop, which version is that exactly? Adding the COM Outlook Object Library 16.0 would refer to the GAC of Outlook Interop 15.0.0.0.